# Javascript FileReader doesn't fire events on large files

Tags: javascript, html, events, filereader, large-files

I'm trying to play the video files from and on client's computer. The thing is it's pretty difficult to get the absolute path so I can put it in `video`'s `src` or `object`'s `data` attribute. Eventually I find the FileReader object, and it works on small files pretty well. However, it doesn't fire the onload event when reading large files (200MB+ so far). No error, FileReader.onerror doesn't fire anything, try/catch doesn't help. Developer console doesn't show anything.

I think it has something to do with max file size on each browser's config, but I can't find the way to configure that. Help?

Here's the code

```
function onclick()
{
            var file_dialog = document.getElementById("file_dialog");
            var path_dialog = document.getElementById("path_dialog");
            var video_player = document.getElementById("video_player");
            var begin_video = document.getElementById("begin_video");
            var reading_progress = document.getElementById("reading_progress");
            file_dialog.onchange = function ()
            {
                begin_video.disabled = file_dialog.files.length == 0 || path_dialog.files.length == 0;
            };
            path_dialog.onchange = file_dialog.onchange;
            begin_video.onclick = function ()
            {
                begin_video.disabled = true;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e)
                {
                    video_player.src = e.target.result;
                    begin_video.disabled = false;
                };
                reader.onprogress = function (e)
                {
                    reading_progress.textContent = "Reading... " + (Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 10000) / 100) + "%";
                };
                reader.onloadend = function (e)
                {
                    if (e.target.error != null)
                        reading_progress.textContent = e.target.error.code;
                    else
                        reading_progress.textContent = "FINISHED!!!";
                };
                reader.onerror = alert;
                reader.readAsDataURL(file_dialog.files[0]);
                var reader2 = new FileReader();
                reader2.onload = function (e)
                {

                };
            };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such browser config setting for this. 
I've also worked with FileReader and large files (up to 50 MB) and the browsers behave very different:

1. Chrome => did well and was the most "responsive"
2. Firefox => did not as well as Chrome, high memory consumption, but worked
3. IE => worked as long the file was below 15 MB, above the browser just didn't process the file - no feedback, didn't fire any event

Maybe it's a memory issue - tested same files with different machine with less memory and IE denied to work already at 5 MB files.